# How to place dynamic value in contentful?

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I am using contentful. In one of the content model, I want to display dynamic value based on the option selected.

e.g. In contentful, I am having message as: Congratulations, your <USER_TYPE> account has created successfully.

I have options as admin/moderator/user then if

1. I select admin, message should get display as: Congratulations, your admin account has created successfully.
2. I select moderator, message should get displayed as: Congratulations, your moderator account has created successfully.

How can I replace <USER_TYPE> with the selected values? Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

In contentful, put the variable as {{ variable_name }} and in the code replace that variable_name with dynamic value as:

```
import Mustache from 'mustache';
Mustache.render(value, {variable_name: variable_value});
```

I am using vueJs, so this implementation refers javascript.

Comment: the same as what i think, but I m still wondering if there is any better option.